# Bitcoin-Qt wallet passphrase help

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-core, passphrase

I do not remember being asked for a passphrase when I installed Bitocoin-Qt (0.8.2 - Beta) (though it was a couple months ago, I could be mistaken) and now am being asked for a passphrase.  I have no idea what it is.  Can this passphrase be reset?  If it cannot, are there restrictions on what can be used for the passphrase (i.e. only letters and numbers) ?

Comment: Being asked for a pass-phrase or to set one to encrypt your wallet? Sorry, need to clarify what you're referring to.

Answer (score 1):

No, it cannot be reset. Yes, I believe it can only include letters and numbers.

Comment: I just made one that included a symbol.